# Twilio Voice. Add another participant to existing call

Tags: twilio, voice, conference

There is an ongoing call between 2 numbers (Twilio to Twilio, or Twilio to any PTSN number). It is not a conference call, just a normal 1-to-1 call using Twilio Voice.

How can I add another person to that call?

This is my current scenario.
I first create a normal call (that has  a ‘timeout’ and then redirects to voicemail via the  ‘action’ verb).
This is working, so a call now exists between 2 parties.

Then if the call initiator wants to add a 2nd number (ie create a conference call), I need to move both the call initiator and the 1st called number into a named conference.

However, I don’t know the Sid of the 1st called number’s leg of the call (I only know the Sid of the parent call), so how can this be done?

Assuming I did manage to create a conference call with the 2 initial numbers, how can I add further numbers to the conference, and automatically terminate the conference when there is only 1 party left?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are looking to add people to a call, then I would recommend you start with a conference call as it's going to be much easier than moving the two legs (though you can find a call by it's parent sid by [listing calls and filtering by `ParentCallSid`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#read-multiple-call-resources)).

Once you have a conference call with your callers in, you can [add a new participant by making a POST request to the participants endpoint](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant?code-sample=code-create-agent-conference-participant&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=5.x#create-a-participant-agent-conference-only).

To end the conference when there is only one participant left, you could set up to receive [conference status callback events when participants leave](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallbackEvent). When you receive the webhook you could then use the [conference SID to look up how many participants are in the conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant#read-multiple-participant-resources) and [end it](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference#update-a-conference-resource) if there is only one left.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I've tried this in my own app and there's simply no separate call sid created for the receiving party on an outbound call. A calls B. Filter call list. There's just a call sid for A and not a distinct one for B. The parent call sid and the call sid are the same.