# How to add another number to the current call using Twilio?

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api, voice, twilio-conference

I am developing a Java application using Twilio. So I was able to create a call between two users. One to one call. But I need to add another person/number to that ongoing call. Like a group call If I needed it. So basically there are two people who are in a call and if the creator of the call (Twilio number user) should be able to add another person to that call. So how can I achieve that? I have checked the conference call.

But the issue is if I did manage to create a conference call with the two numbers, but how can I add another number to that ongoing conference call?

Comment: This question looks related and the answer might answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52778446/twilio-voice-add-another-participant-to-existing-call?rq=1

Comment: I checked it but It's not helped me. Because I need add the another number dynamically. If I want a group call I want to add another number and if I don't then just the one to one call.

Answer (score 0):

would adding a `<Gather>` with a long timeout help? You can set any key you decide which would start a function that prompts you to enter a number to dial out.

Comment: I am not clear about it. Can you show by a sample code snippet?